# what happens if pthread_mutex_t, pthread_cond_t are destroyed when pthread_cond_wait() is still active?

Tags: pthreads

`pthread_cond_wait()` is woken by `pthread_cond_signal()` when I receive certain response. But in some cases, I do not get a response. So in those cases, when I simply destroy the `pthread_mutex_t`, `pthread_cond_t` it seems to be still continuing in an infinite loop.

I do not understand if this is the reason or anything else. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of `pthread_cond_wait()` is undefined when its mutex is destroyed.

More than that, `pthread_cond_wait()` should be called when its associated mutex is locked,
otherwise the functions' behavior is also undefined.

The function also establishes a dynamic bind between the mutex and the condition variable (when the function returns, the bind is released too). Therefore destroying the condition variable also may lead to undefined behavior.

More details can be found here:
[opengroup: pthread_cond_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html)

Comment: Trying to destroy 'pthread_cond_t' is resulting EBUSY error. So first I send 'pthread_cond_signal' & then destroying 'pthread_cond_t'. But this is seems to be inlogical solution. Can you suggest a better idea??

Comment: @unix_kid. Maybe you do not need to destroy the condition variable and the mutex (at least at the early stage) at all, reusing them instead of destroying? Or, if you are forced to destroy by some requirements, do it when you are sure that no thread is using neither the mutex nor the cond variable.